# C/C# - Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi

Tags: c#, c

What's the equivalent to Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi (C#) in C language ?

Because, I would like rewrite a function C# in C. 
This is the C# function:

```
public int GetProcessName(uint processId, out string name)
        {
            IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)(0x211)); int result = -1;
            result = getProcessName(processId, ptr);
            name = String.Empty;
            if(SUCCESS(result))
                name = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
            return result;
        }
```

And actually my C function:

```
int
GetProcessName(uint processId, char *name)
{
    HINSTANCE   hLib = LoadLibrary("CCAPI.DLL");
     __cGetProcessName      getProcessName = (__cGetProcessName)GetProcAddress(hLib, "CCAPIGetProcessName");
    int     *ptr = malloc((int)(0x211));
    int     result = -1;
    result = getProcessName(processId, ptr);

    name = "";
    if (SUCCESS(result))
    {
        name = /* ?? */;
    }

    free(ptr);
    return (result);
}
```

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. C doesn't need marshaling in the first place.

Comment: You'll have to rewrite your question to explain your *actual* problem. Please read [what's the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271659) to get you on the right track.

Comment: By the way, you forgot the `FreeLibrary` call (you could also load the library just once and reuse the handle, that would be even better).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C#, `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi` takes a pointer and returns a `string`.

In C, there is no `string` type and nothing equivalent out of the box. The closest you can have is a `char*` that points to an array of characters terminated with a null character (`'\0'`). By convention, we call this a "C string" (even though it's not a type of its own).

Thus, if you have a `char*`, you already have the C equivalent of the output of a `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi` on that `char*` (as a `IntPtr`) in C#.

So this line:

```
name = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);
```

Would have been something like this:

```
name = ptr;
```

But since you seem to be freeing the `ptr` buffer at the end and you want the result in the externally provided buffer `name`, the correct alternative in C would actually be:

```
strcpy(name, ptr);
```

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski In that way you are creating a memory leak

Comment: @theo It is very important to specify who own the memory at the end, so you should really add a "but remember to `free()` the memory somewhere"

Comment: @xanatos actually nevermind, he fixed the answer, I was referring to the previous version.